# How to integrate Xcode with SVN

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, version-control

I have an existing iPhone project in SVN. I want to manage it all through Xcode.

Is there any way I can integrate SVN with Xcode so that all SVN operations are possible thru Xcode?

Comment: Just a suggestion since I have had a headache with this... After you learn how to integrate that with svn, don't forget to place the build folder outside the project folder.

Comment: Xcode's SVN implementation is riddled with bugs (and has an unintuitive operation flow). Use a third-party GUI like Versions/Cornerstone.

Comment: Any example of such bugs? I was looking into http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeSourceManagement/30-Source_Control/source_control.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002686-BAJCEFIF and finding it good. What consequences I may have to face?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 3.x already has SVN support built-in, which may well be sufficient for your requirements. (See the [Xcode Source Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeSourceManagement/30-Source_Control/source_control.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002686-BAJCEFIF) for details of the built-in capabilities.)

I believe that Xcode 4.x will offer some nice improvements to this as well (see the "Version Editor" blurb in the [What's new in Xcode 4 document](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html)), but this is still a beta product and not for production use.